# How to roll a cube on it's edges on Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, physics, cube, rigid-bodies

I want to move a cube by making it roll on it's edges. The cube will be standing on a x-z grid and each movement it takes will make it stand on a different square of the grid.

The player will controll the movement and will only be able to make the cube roll on one direction at a time (left, right, forward or back), but the cube must always stand exactly on top of one of the grid's squares.

I don't think applying a force to the cube will help cause it could move it a little bit too much or too little. I want to achieve something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yaAIUYuNi84 but only on the x-z plane. **Notice how on each corner the cube can stop and change direction with ease, because it never moves too much or too little**.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: If you do not want to use force (and you should not) I would make animations for that, shouldn't be very hard.

Comment: I've only been using unity for about a week, haven't tested animations. What would I have to do? Play a rotate animation for every single space moved? Like for when the cube moves one square, animate one rotation?

Comment: Exactly, you can create a simple clip in Unity for rotation. It shouldn't be very hard since it is a simple move of simple object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to the Unity it will be useless to trowing you a bunch of codes so i am telling you the way of doing it so you can implement your own codes.

You can create 4 empty game object which will always follow the cube on the floor and when you want to roll the cube you will rotate the cube around the empty objects.

You can find the codes for following the cube and rotating the cube on youtube, and for the starters searching is allways good.

So i hope you can manage it out, if you cant please write me again where did you stuck and i will be happy to answer you :)

Comment: You mean each of the 4 empty objects will be positioned on each edge of the cube? I would actually need 6 cause the movement will be on all directions. Nonetheless, if this the case I will have to rotate the cube using `rotateAround` right? I'm trying to implement it right now, let me know if I got it wrong. Thanks for answering, and yes, my experience with Unity is one week :).

Comment: @somezombie yes rotateAround will  work and on the Update method you can constantly update the position of the empty objects by the 1 or 3 px ofset on the ground and with this do can do it with only 4 object, other than that you need to check which side is the cube on so you can rotate it around

Comment: @somezombie try this and like i said, anytime feel free to ask question when you get stuck :)

Comment: I'm working on it, i'll let you know how it goes. The empty objects will be a child of the cube so they rotate along with it.

Comment: @somezombie well if you make the objects child of the cube they will rotate with cube but if you dont make them child and you make them follow cube by code then they wont rotate with the and with that you can create more clean code :)

Comment: @somezombie and as an additional fact you dont need any code to follow the cube if you make the empty objects child of the cube, they will be same possition locally to the cube, still it will be more harder to achive your solition while objects are rotating :)

Comment: Yeah there is a problem with this. If I make them children of the cube, then graphically they will rotate with the cube but logically their position will remain the same relative to the cube.

Comment: @somezombie you are rotating the cube by the world coordinats, it may causs a problem to make the objects childs of the cube, but still you can try both of them and see which one perform better :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to move the cube one position for now, but this is the answer I was looking for; help on how to approach the issue. So basically for moving on every direction on the x-z plane I will have to 1) Create 8 empty game objects, one for each edge of the cube, 2) Figure out where the player wants to move 3) Rotate the cube around the respective edge using rotateAround. Also note that the empty game objects are children of the cube. Unity lets us use their global or local position :)